# Почему buffer при использовании ReadProcessMemory заполняется нулями?

Tags: c#, .net, память, процесс

Есть программа которая получает значение ячейки памяти занятой процессом "notepad++", в буфер должно заносится содержание этой ячейки, но почему-то он заполнен нулями.Почему?

```
class Program
{

    public enum DesiredAccessProcess : uint
    {
        PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x0001,
        PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002,
        PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008,
        PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010,
        PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020,
        PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE = 0x0040,
        PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x0080,
        PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x0100,
        PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION = 0x0200,
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400,
        SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = SYNCHRONIZE | 0xF0FFF
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(DesiredAccessProcess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern void ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, uint size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    public byte[] ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr MemoryAddress, uint bytesToRead, out int bytesRead, IntPtr handle)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
        IntPtr ptrBytesRead;
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, MemoryAddress, buffer, bytesToRead, out ptrBytesRead);
        int result = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        bytesRead = ptrBytesRead.ToInt32();
        return buffer;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint m_startAddress = 0, // Адрес, с которого начинается сканирование
         m_scanLength = 1000000000, // Длина сканируемой области в байтах
         m_bytesRead; // Количество прочитанных байт
        byte[] buffer = new byte[m_scanLength];
        int[] nums = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = 1;
        }
        Process m_process=new Process();
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processes)
            if (process.ProcessName == "notepad++")
                m_process = process;
        if (m_process != null)
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                IntPtr m_intptrProcess = OpenProcess(DesiredAccessProcess.PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, (uint)m_process.Id); 
                ReadProcessMemory(m_intptrProcess, (IntPtr)m_startAddress, buffer, m_scanLength, out m_bytesRead);
                for (int i = 0; i < m_scanLength; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(buffer[i]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Почему вы не проверяете, что возвращает OpenProcess и ReadProcessMemory?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы ReadProcessMemory отработала успешно, нужно следующее:

1. Дескриптор процесса должен быть открыт с правом PROCESS_VM_READ. У вас он открывается с правом PROCESS_TERMINATE, что явно не то.
2. **Вся** запрашиваемая область памяти быть доступна на чтение. Так как вы запрашиваете область, начинающуюся от нулевого байта, у вас всегда будет выбивать ошибку, ведь часть младших адресов памяти зарезервирована для отлова багов с обращением к нулевым указателям и недоступна на чтение. Нужно считывать память блоками меньшего размера.

Также, для адресов лучше использовать тип IntPtr, а не uint, иначе программа не сможет корректно работать при 64-битной целевой архитектуре.

Пример считывания первого доступного блока памяти в 1024 байта:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum DesiredAccessProcess : uint
        {
            PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x0001,
            PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002,
            PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008,
            PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010,
            PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020,
            PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE = 0x0040,
            PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x0080,
            PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x0100,
            PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION = 0x0200,
            PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400,
            SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
            PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = SYNCHRONIZE | 0xF0FFF
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(DesiredAccessProcess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, IntPtr size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr m_startAddress = (IntPtr)0; // Адрес, с которого начинается сканирование
            IntPtr m_scanLength = (IntPtr)1024; // Длина сканируемой области в байтах
            IntPtr m_bytesRead; // Количество прочитанных байт
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)m_scanLength];

            Process m_process = null;
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad++");
            if (processes.Length == 0) throw new Exception("Can't find process!");
            m_process = processes[0];

            using (m_process)
            {
                IntPtr m_intptrProcess = OpenProcess(DesiredAccessProcess.PROCESS_VM_READ, false, (uint)m_process.Id);
                if (m_intptrProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                for (UInt64 n = 0; n < UInt64.MaxValue - (UInt64)m_scanLength; n += (UInt64)m_scanLength)
                {
                    m_startAddress = (IntPtr)n;
                    Console.Write("Address 0x" + n.ToString("X").PadLeft(16, '0') + ": ");

                    int res = ReadProcessMemory(m_intptrProcess, (IntPtr)m_startAddress, buffer, m_scanLength, out m_bytesRead);
                    if (res == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ReadProcessMemory failed. Code: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bytes read: {0}", m_bytesRead);
                        for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_scanLength; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(buffer[i].ToString("X").PadLeft(2,'0') + " ");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```